# Filtering array inside and array using jsonpath in java

Tags: java, jsonpath

I am trying to get a value which is in an array under and array and an object with a filter but not able to achive what I want . I am using github.com/json-path/JsonPath.

I need to get value case_identifier__c where source__c in ['nci__c'].

```
{
  "case_version__v": {
    "case_number__vr": {
      "id": "V2A000000001002",
      "none2b_references__cr": [
        {
          "case_number__c": "V2A000000001002",
          "case_identifier__c": "THIS-IS-MINE",
          "id": "V8C000000001001",
          "source__c": [
            "nci__c"
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

I have tried below JSONPATH but it returns me an empty value instead of [THIS-IS-MINE]

```
$..case_version__v.case_number__vr.none2b_references__cr[?(@.source__c in ['nci__c'])].case_identifier__c
```

Comment: Can you show us your Java code for evaluating the jsonpath? Different libraries have different quirks.

Comment: I am using https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath. Are there any other popular java libraries other than this ? Also I tried Intellij’s inbuilt Jaon expression evaluator and it also does not give me the desired output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when you use the `in` filter operator only the right-side expression should contain an array while the left side should be a single value.

using `in` filter operator

```
$..case_version__v.case_number__vr.none2b_references__cr[?('nci__c' in @.source__c)].case_identifier__c
```

Comment: use `subsetof`, `anyof` or `noneof` when you want to have arrays on both side of expression

Comment: Thanks Akshay, using subset worked